# SELECT row, COUNT(*) FROM table; returns only one result instead of all

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MySQL and ran across something interesting that is happening behind the scenes and I would like to know the reason I get the output that I do.

In my case I have a table of books and I am running

```
SELECT released_year, COUNT(*) FROM books;
```

and my output is

```
+---------------+----------+
| released_year | COUNT(*) |
+---------------+----------+
|          2003 |       19 |
+---------------+----------+
```

Now obviously there are a ton more released_year's than 2003 and I'm curious why using COUNT limits my results to just one entry instead of getting the full row back?

Comment: This query should have given a error based on the ANSI/ISO SQL standard syntax rules about [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) -> *"If a query has aggregate functions and no GROUP BY clause, it cannot have nonaggregated columns in the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled: "*   sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled  forces MySQL to respect those ANSI SQL GROUP BY rules, on your server that sql_mode is not active.

Comment: add `GROUP BY released_year`  and maybe a `ORDER BY released_year ASC`

Comment: Furthermore, by omitting the `group by` clause you are essentially saying "Return the total of count(*) from the table, and one random `released_year`" which is almost never desirable. Mysql made a change to its default behavior in versions 5.7 and newer that make it act like every other RDBMS on the planet where this SQL would throw an error, as it should.

Comment: What @JNevill says about *"Return the total of count(*) from the table, and one random released_year"* is also mentioned in the manual `SELECT released_year, COUNT(*) FROM books; ` runs internally more or less like `SELECT ANY_VALUE(released_year), COUNT(*) FROM books` on those older non supporting or disabled ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY MySQL servers.. As without GROUP BY the column released_year is nondeterministic ("random") choosen

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to include the `GROUP BY column_name` section of the **SELECT** query ,as specified here in [W3Tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) SQL Group by section, when using a field. You could only run an aggregate function without a GROUP BY if there is no column names in the SELECT portion of the query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM books;
```

When using an AGGREGATE functions like [COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) with a field(s) then you need to make sure that you are including a `GROUP BY` statement with that field(s). For your example it would be as follows:

```
SELECT released_year, COUNT(*) 
FROM books 
GROUP BY released_year;
```

Unfortunately sometimes either the RDBMS driver or the client you are using might try to evaluate the SQL beforehand and if it doesn't make sense it would tweak it. In this particular situation it could be the version of MySQL you are using isn't yet including the generic group by error.